# Proof of coercivity and compactness of a continuous function using contradiction?

Tags: calculus, continuity, compactness

The goal here is to prove the following statement:

If the set $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is compact, then the function $f$ is coercive.

I saw a so-called **answer** to this proof, but it does not seem convincing to me.  It says

> assume each of the sets $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is bounded and let
>   $\{x^v\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $||x^v|| \rightarrow
> > \infty$. Let us suppose that there exists a subsequence of the
>   integers $J\subset \mathbb{N}$  such that the set $\{f(x^v)\}_J$ is
>   bounded above.  Then there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $\{x^v\}_J \subset \{x|f(x)\le \alpha \}$.  But this cannot be the
>   case since each of the sets $\{x|f(x)\le\alpha\}$ is bounded while
>   every subsequence of the sequence $\{x^v\}$ is unbounded by
>   definition. Therefore, the set $\{f(x^v)\}_J$ cannot be bounded, and
>   so the sequence $\{f(x^v)\}$ contains no bounded subsequence, i.e.
>   $f(x^v)\rightarrow\infty$.

I do not understand this answer, and specifically this sentence in the answer: “But this cannot be the case since each of the sets $\{x|f(x)\le\alpha\}$ is bounded while every subsequence of the sequence $\{x^v\}$ is unbounded by definition.”

If we are claiming that this sentence is a contradiction, then in that case the very first sentence of this answer, we have already reached the contradiction!   The very first sentence reads: “assume each of the sets $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is bounded and let $\{x^v\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $||x^v|| \rightarrow \infty$”. Which, as far as i can tell, is the same as what the proof is saying "cannot be the case".  Is that true?

I do not understand how this proof is proceeding to show a contradiction, when to me it has already shown it in the first sentence just by assuming a contradiction.  Can someone helps me understands this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the sequences $x^v$, which is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and whose norms tend to $\infty$, and $f(x^v)$, which is in $\mathbb{R}$ and may or may not tend to $\infty$ itself.

That said, I think the proof is a little bit tricky to follow, so let me see if I can write the same idea a little clearer.

> We wish to show that $f$ is coercive, that is, given a sequence $(x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|x_k\| \to \infty$, we must necessarily have $f(x_k) \to \infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $(x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|x_k\| \to \infty$, but $f(x_k) \not\to \infty$. Then there exists some subsequence $x_{k_m}$ such that $f(x_{k_m})$ (not $x_{k_m}$!) is bounded above. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be such a bound, i.e. so that $f(x_{k_m}) \le \alpha$ for all $m$. That is,
> $$x_{k_m} \in \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) \le \alpha \rbrace.$$
> Since this set is compact, some convergent subsequence $x_{k_{m_l}}$ exists in the above set. Since $x_{k_{m_l}}$ is convergent, it is also bounded, meaning that $\|x_{k_{m_l}}\| < \beta$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. But $\|x_k\| \to \infty$, which means that no subsequence can be bounded, so we have a contradiction.

EDIT: Question 1: A real sequence that does not tend to positive $\infty$ always has a subsequence that is bounded above (in fact, tending to $\infty$ is equivalent to having no subsequence that is bounded above). I am applying this to the sequence $f(x_k)$. To prove this, we can go back to the $M$-$N$ definition of of convergence to $\infty$.

Suppose $a_n$ is a real sequence. By definition, we say $a_n \to \infty$ if, for all $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies a_n \ge M.$$
That is, $a_n$ becomes larger than any bound, and eventually stays larger.

If we take the negation of this, $a_n \not\to \infty$ means that, there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ with the property that, for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $n \ge N$ such that $a_n < M$.

If we take $\alpha$ to be this value of $M$, then using $N = 1$, there exists an $n_1 \ge 1$ such that $a_{n_1} < \alpha$. We can do this again with $N = n_1 + 1$. This gives us $n_2 \ge n_1 + 1$ such that $a_{n_2} < \alpha$. Recursively, we continue building this sequence so that $n_{k+1} \le n_k + 1$, but still $a_{n_k} < \alpha$. That is, we've built a bounded subsequence.

Like I said before, I used this on $f(x_k)$. This gave us a bounded above subsequence $f(x_{k_m}) \le \alpha$.

Question 2: Convergence (to something finite) always implies boundedness; there is no need for any kind of compactness. Suppose $x_n \to L$ and pick your favourite value of $\varepsilon > 0$ (I'll take $1$, because I'm boring). By definition of convergence, there exists some $N$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies \|x_n - L\| < 1 \implies |\|x_n\| - \|L\|| < 1 \implies \|x_n\| < 1 + \|L\|,$$
by the reverse triangle inequality. This only covers $x_N, x_{N+1}, x_{N+2}, \ldots$. However, the rest is a finite set of points, which is bounded, so we have,
$$\|x_n\| \le \max \lbrace \|x_1\|, \|x_2\|, \ldots, \|x_{N-1}\|, 1 + \|L\| \rbrace$$
for all $n$.

Question 3: That's too general. The question says that the lower level sets of the function are compact, which I definitely need in the proof. I'm assuming that the sequence in the codomain $f(x_k)$ does not tend to $\infty$. Then I apply the result from question 1.

The result from question 1 gives me a bounded subsequence. I then take this back to the domain. Boundedness tells me that it belongs to one of these compact lower level sets, so we apply the definition of compactness to get a subsequence in the domain that converges.

Finally, I apply the result from question 2: the convergent subsequence is bounded. This can't happen, since the sequence in the domain is supposed to tend (in norm) to $\infty$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me understand this better, @TheoBendit.  Now, what allows us to say that if there exists a subsequence $\{x_{km}\}$ such that $f(x_k)$ is bounded, then there exists some subsequence $\{x_{km}\}\subset\{x_{k}\}$ such that $f(x_{km}) \le \alpha  \forall x_{km}$ ?

Comment: Another question (and thank you for your attention @TheoBendit).  You seem to be saying $\{x_{kml}\}\subset\{x_{km}\}$ converges, right?  And, convergence implies boundedness since the set is compact?  (or does compactness have nothing to do with it)?

Comment: Part of my confusion is around, as you pointed out, drawing conclusions of convergence in the codomain based on sequences in the domain.  So, here I will try to summarize the theorem that you are employing to make your answer: *If there exists a sequence on the domain such that the codomain converges to something, then there exists a subsequence in the domain such that the codomain is bounded on that entire subsequence.*

Comment: @Hunle Hi. I've edit my answer, somewhat substantially, to answer your questions. Let me know if you need any further clarification. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response @TheoBendit, that is a thorough answer.  For the first one, about “A real sequence that does not tend to…” all we really care about is the sequence of $\{f(x_k)\}$ values, not the $\{x_k\}$ sequence, then, right?  You start your simplified proof with “…contradiction…$(x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ...” which originally made me think that you were concerned somehow with the sequences on the $(x_k)$ values.  But you’re telling me that we can likely discard that part.

Comment: Okay, so the only time you can draw conclusions about the codomain, based on the domain, is when you are effectively using the domain as an *index* to the codomain, OR ,when you are using it as in the premise of the question: in the definition of coercivity.

Comment: @Hunle Everything in the argument is important. We need facts about the sequence in the codomain to say something about the sequence in the domain. And yes, they are connected, by their common indexes. As we remove points from $f(x_k)$ so that $f(x_k)$ becomes bounded above, so too can we remove the corresponding points from the sequence $x_k$. Removing the corresponding points puts the resulting subsequence $(x_{k_m})$ in a compact set - the corresponding boundedness of $f(x_k)$ is what makes this happen!